# Helm Kubernetes ConfigMap unexpected "\\" in define clause

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, configmap

I'm getting the following error triying to import a JSON into a ConfigMap YAML and then creating the chart.

```
[ERROR] templates/: parse error at (mychart/templates/provision.yml:50): unexpected "\\" in define clause
```

The configmap YAML is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: provisioning
  labels:
    app: provisioning
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
data:
  provisioning.json: |
    [...foo...]
                {
                    "name": "Notification Channel",
                    "request": {
                        "method": "POST",
                        "header": [],
                        "body": {
                            "mode": "raw",
                            "raw": "{\r\n    \"template_files\": {\r\n        \"Teams\": \"{{ define \\\"Teams\\\" }}\\n  {{ range .Alerts }}\\n    · Alerta: {{ .Labels.alertname }}\\n    · Estado: {{ .Status }}\\n    · Link: {{ .PanelURL }}\\n    · Hora Inicio: {{ .StartsAt }}\\n    {{ if eq .Status \\\"firing\\\" }}· Causante: {{ .ValueString }}{{ end }}{{ if eq .Status \\\"resolved\\\" }}· Hora Fin: {{ .EndsAt}}{{ end }}\\n  {{ end }}\\n{{ end }}\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"alertmanager_config\": {\r\n        \"route\": {\r\n            \"receiver\": \"Teams\"\r\n        },\r\n        \"templates\": [\r\n            \"Teams\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"receivers\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"name\": \"Teams\",\r\n                \"grafana_managed_receiver_configs\": [\r\n                    {\r\n                        \"uid\": \"\",\r\n                        \"name\": \"Teams\",\r\n                        \"type\": \"teams\",\r\n                        \"disableResolveMessage\": false,\r\n                        \"settings\": {\r\n                            \"message\": \"{{ template \\\"Teams\\\" . }}\",\r\n                            \"url\": \"https://t2cspain.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/b21022ce-5ce7-4e6f-a1a1-d429d039b0cb@87dfd7ae-c707-4e66-b4ca-36f953322bec/IncomingWebhook/192cb46181614c60a471cb6751402c95/f557ae60-9097-4696-97b8-f47c45523633\"\r\n                        },\r\n                        \"secureFields\": {}\r\n                    }\r\n                ]\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n}",
                            "options": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "language": "json"
                                }
                            }
                        }
     [...foo...]
```

Line 50 is the `"raw": "{\r\n...` line.

I believe it's because the "define" word is not escaping properly.

PD: I do not get this error when applying the yaml directly using `kubectl`.